# Replacing the value 1 with the word Ace in a deck of cards

Tags: python, python-3.x

We got the assignement to make a program that shuffles a deck of cards. I'm still quite new to programming so this hasn't been the easiest assignement to do for me. We got the tip to do some research into itertools, so that's what I did. The program I have so far is as followed:

```
import itertools
import random

deck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),['Heart','Spade','Club','Diamond']))

random.shuffle(deck)

print("Order of deck:")
for i in range(52):
    print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1])
```

If you run this you get:

```
Order of deck:
9 of Heart
10 of Diamond
2 of Spade
1 of Heart
11 of Spade
4 of Diamond
10 of Heart
...
```

You get a shuffled deck, as I wanted.

The only thing left to do is to change the values of 1 to "Ace", 11 to "Jack", ...

But I can't figure out how to do this, because my list "deck" consists of 52 items with each card as a tuple. For example

```
deck[0] = (1, 'Spade')
```

So far the only things I learned to replace are

```
deck.replace(1,"Ace")
```

and

```
for n, i in enumerate(deck):
    if i == 1:
        deck[n] = "Ace"
```

But these both don't work.
The first one doesn't work because my deck isn't a string, but a list.
And if I run the second one nothing changes, the output remains the exact same as without that piece of code.

So to sum everything up, I want to change the 1 to "Ace" in my little program, and then I could do the same for 11 to "Jack", ...
(Sorry for any bad English, hope everything is clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your list with the strings that you would like to display:

```
values = ['Ace'] + [str(i) for i in range(2,11)] + ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
suits = ['Heart', 'Spade', 'Club', 'Diamond']
deck = list(itertools.product(values, suits))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this, depending on what you're trying to do. If you want to capture the notion that the value of Jack is 11, then you'll need to change only the displayed value (i.e. check before you print and replace `11` with `Jack`, etc). However, if the value isn't of particular concern, then you can fiddle with the deck at creation time:

```
deck = list(itertools.product(["A", *range(2,11), 'J', 'Q', 'K'],['Heart','Spade','Club','Diamond']))
```

Comment: This gave an IndexErrox (list index out of range) at the print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1]) line, but it also returned output like "range(2,11) of Heart

Comment: @ZinoWR: oops! sorry, I had a typo there (notice the `*`). Check it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace anything. You can use a function to return the appropriate string value

```
def get_face(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'Ace' 
    elif x == 11:
        return 'Jack' 
    else:  # TODO: add others 
        return x

for card in deck:
    print(get_face(card[0]), "of", card[1])
```

Comment: this also fixed it, but I can only give one the green check and the other one was shorter 